# Not known class method for selector OpenDevice

Tags: objective-c, macos, exception, crash

I'm developing an app in Objective-c for OSX.

I have write a first class and try to call this class in my MainThread.

The build succeed but the app crash

DeviceManager.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DeviceManager : NSObject

+(void)DeviceManager:OpenDevice;

@end
```

DeviceManager.m

```
#import "DeviceManager.h"

@implementation DeviceManager

- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        NSLog(@"Init");
    }
    return self;
}

+ (void)DeviceManager:OpenDevice {
    NSLog(@"Opening Device");
}

@end
```

The main.m is calling it:

```
#import "DeviceManager.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    [DeviceManager OpenDevice];
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

At build, I have Not known class method for selector OpenDevice

Thx
Seb

Comment: First, one question per post. Second, what are the exception and crash message?

Comment: @Josh, I change the description following a code change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DeviceManager : NSObject

+ (void) openDevice;

@end
```

DeviceManager.m

```
#import "DeviceManager.h"

@implementation DeviceManager

+ (void) openDevice {
    NSLog(@"Opening Device");
}

@end
```

main.m

```
#import "DeviceManager.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    [DeviceManager openDevice];
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

The above works for me. What does `DeviceManager:OpenDevice` mean? Because unless it's a new way to define methods it's gibberish. It looks like you want a class method for Device Manager called openDevice... so use `+ (void) openDevice {...}`.

Comment: `+ (void)DeviceManager:OpenDevice;` is a class method named `DeviceManager:` returning nothing and taking one argument; the name of the argument is `OpenDevice` and its type is `id`. A legal declaration but terrible style.

Comment: I figured it was legal as it compiled without warning, good to know why though. Thanks. I guess I should've thought about it for a second and explained what the definition actually defined before showing them how to define what they intended.